# What is the significance of tactical strike team missions?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

I'm [having a hard time doing these missions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/92924/how-can-i-win-tactical-strike-force-missions), and apparently there's a limited time window for me to do them. Are there any rewards or penalties for completing or failing to complete these missions?

Comment: The hardest part about these missions is the incredibly poor AI of my units. Unless I am physically controlling a team member, they will blindly walk single-file into an enemy kill zone while moving. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completing all of the levels will make the later parts of the campaign easier, because

> China will not go to war against US and will send military help.

An extra strike team mission will let you fix you mistake you can make during one of the campaign mission, specifically

> Failing to save the scientist lady from abduction.